# Bootstrap Page not Working: Extra Line Breaks and Drop Down Menu Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

I have a website that utilizes Bootstrap. It has been online for several days. Just today, however, the drop down menu stopped working, and there was a line break betweent the menu and the body. Is this an issue just for me or for others who use Bootstrap as well. After the navbar, I have a blue strip that fades in.
What's causing the problem, and is it just my problem? How do you solve it? Thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse net-27" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contribute</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span> Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                            <center>

                                <div id="test" style="background-color:#001A57; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Lucida Bright, Arial, sans-serif";>
                                    <p style="text-align:center;">Welcome!</p>
                                    <br /><p id="nothuge" class="plzplz"></p>
                                    <br />
                                    <p style="font-size:20px;">--Site Info--</p>
                                    <br /><p style="font-size:30px;">
                                    <a href="#">Login/Register</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                            </center>
            </div>


            <!-- /.row -->

            <div class="row">

                    <center>
                    <p class="lead">Text</p>
                    <p class="intro-line2" id="bittearbeit">MoreText</p>
                    </center>
                </div>
            <footer class="margin-tb-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p>© My Site 2017 | contact@my.site</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

</body>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/user2015748/g776473m/1/)
I have a lot of CSS with that, which you can see in the JSFiddle. 
As you can see, there is no code for a line break after the navbar. Thank you again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CSS statement that adds this line. Its a "margin-bottom: 20px;"
Try this:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```